# Plot channel vs error probability

Tags: matlab

How to give relation between channel vs error probability .with the given marginal probability and to Comment on result based on finding.

How to approach this question?
Can someone please help?

Comment: This is not a site for homework service. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: @Sadd I am just asking the relationship between these two.